# Using forEach to chain methods

Tags: javascript

One of the advantages I've heard for the use of `forEach` vs a `for/of` on an iterable is that you can chain methods together.

As a basic example of the two I have:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr.forEach((elem, idx) => {
    console.log(elem);
})
for (let elem of arr) {
    console.log(elem);
};
```

What would be an example of chaining together multiple `forEach`'s?

Comment: Well you can't chain together multiple `forEach`s since `Array.prototype.forEach` returns undefined no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` returns `undefined`. You can't call a method on `undefined`.

The chaining you might have heard about is when forEach is at the end of some processing which returns an array, like after array methods like `map`,`reduce` etc:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];

arr.map(x => x*2).forEach((elem, idx) => {
    console.log(elem);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` always returns `undefined`. `forEach` is not chain-able like `map`, `reduce` or `filter`.